# how to handle remote control with two alternating signals per button

Tags: linux, lirc

I have captured the ir signal for dishtv remote control and converted to dishtv.lircd.conf file.I am getting below error while sending ir signal using irsend command. How to create proper config file if remote could have two alternating signals per remote

```
unknown remote: "dishtv"
Error running command: Input/output error
```

Here is the content of licrd.conf file for dishtv remote

```
# Please make this file available to others
# by sending it to <lirc@bartelmus.de>
#
# this config file was automatically generated
# using lirc-0.9.0(default) on Mon Oct 19 15:20:38 2020
#
# contributed by 
#
# brand:                       dishtv.lirc.conf
# model no. of remote control: 
# devices being controlled by this remote:
#

begin remote

  name  dishtv
  flags RAW_CODES
  eps            30
  aeps          100

  gap          200323

      begin raw_codes

          name ok
              868     802    1720    1646    1695     828
              849     831     849    1674    1695     828
              849    1674     849     831     849     831
              849     831    1695

      end raw_codes

end remote
```